# How does NotificationHub remove the registration devices

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, uninstallation, azure-notificationhub

In the diagnostic console in visual studio under the Azure->NotificationHub, after I registered my device to the hub, the expiration date shown is 9999 years by default. If I removed my application, the registration still exist. Later I re-install the application, a new creation of the registration added to the list. The old registration never get deleted.

Do I have to manually set an expiration date? It sounds not logical, coz the application still using it. How can the Notification Hub delete the old registered devices when the application was uninstalled.

Answer (score 4):

> How can the Notification Hub delete the old registered devices when the application was uninstalled.

AFAIK, you need to explicitly call the related method for removing the registration from azure notification hubs. And there is no event raised when the  app is uninstalled.

As the old documentation about [Registration Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn530747.aspx):

> It is important to note that registrations are transient. Similar to the PNS handles that they contain, registrations expire. **You can set the time to live for a registration on the Notification Hub, up to a maximum of 90 days**. **This limit means that they must be periodically refreshed, and also that they should not be the only store for important information. This automatic expiration also simplifies cleanup when your mobile application is uninstalled.**

While the new [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management) states as follows:

> It is important to note that registrations and installations by default no longer expire.

In summary, you could just remain the old registrations, then the Notification Hubs would clean the registrations as it receives PNS feedback about expired or invalid registrations. Or you could specific the time to live for a registration and periodically update/create it when your app is launching. And the expired registrations would be deleted automatically.

> If I removed my application, the registration still exist. Later I re-install the application, a new creation of the registration added to the list. The old registration never get deleted.

When creating the registration, I would recommend you generate a unique device ID as your device registration ID (e.g. `installationId` for the Installation model, `RegistrationId` for the Registration model), and you could call the related method (e.g. `hub.DeleteRegistrationAsync`) to create or update your device registration. For creating unique device ID, you could refer to [here](http://www.markarteaga.com/getting-unique-device-id-for-ios-android-and-windows-with-xamarin/). Moreover, you could refer to [Registration management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management).